# How to pass value from drop-down list

Tags: spring-mvc, model, thymeleaf

I'm working with the Spring MVC + Thymeleaf project, and I have a problem with passing the field value to object.
There are the `malt` and `country` entities. In `malt` form, there is a drop-down list, that are populated from DB - only country names - nothig fancy. I'm able to populate the list, but when I'm clicking "submit" button, there are some errors. Code below (only relevant parts):

Malt entity:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name="malt")
public class Malt extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="malt_name")
    private String maltName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="producer_id")
    private Producer producer;

    @Column(name="malt_filling")
    private int maltFilling;

    @Column(name="malt_ebc")
    private int maltEbc;

    @Column(name="malt_usage")
    private String maltUsage;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    private Country country;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="malts")
    private Set<Batch> batches;
```

Malt controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/malt")
public class MaltController {

@ModelAttribute("countries")
public Collection<Country> populateCountries() {
    return countryService.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping("{id}/update")
public String updateMalt(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("malt", maltService.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));
    return "malt-form";
}

@PostMapping
public String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute Malt malt) {
    Malt savedMalt = maltService.save(malt);
    return "redirect:/malt/" + savedMalt.getId() + "/malt-show";
}
```

Malt form:

```
<div class="form-field-input">
    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{id}">
        <option value="0">Select country</option>
        <option
            th:each="country : ${countries}"
            th:value="${country.id}"
            th:text="${country?.countryName}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-field-submit">
    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Malt show template:

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <p th:text="${malt.maltName}">Malt name</p>
                </div>
                <div class="show">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-field-name">
                            <label>Producer:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field-input">
                            <p th:text="${malt.producer.producerName}">Producer name</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-field-name">
                            <label>Country:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field-input">
                            <p th:text="${malt.country.countryName}">Country</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-field-name">
                            <label>Malt filling:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field-input">
                            <p th:text="${malt.maltFilling}">Malt filling</p>                       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-field-name">
                            <label>Malt usage:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field-input">
                            <p th:text="${malt.maltUsage}">Malt usage</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-field-name">
                            <label>Malt EBC:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field-input">
                            <p th:text="${malt.maltEbc}">Malt EBC</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

End error that I'm getting:

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/malt-show.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/malt-show.html]")
.
.
.
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "malt.country.countryName" (template: "malt-show" - line 44, col 11)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "malt.country.countryName" (template: "malt-show" - line 44, col 11)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'countryName' cannot be found on null
```

Link to repo: https://github.com/fangirsan/maruszka-new/tree/malt-form-problem

I've tried a lot of different approaches, but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception said, problem is `${malt.country.countryName}` inside your `malt-show` form. In the last line of exception stacktrace, I see `Property or field 'countryName' cannot be found on null`. This means that **you are trying to get a property of related model that is null**. Probably, the column `country_id` in your `malt` table is null. In the other words, `country_id` not saved with the other fields. With these assumptions, you will find the problem in the `malt-form` form where you are saving malts. I inspected this form, probably the problem is `<select class="form-control" th:field="*{id}">`. I think this must be changed to `<select class="form-control" th:field="*{country.id}">`.

**Important Note:**

Some of related models can be null, for example assume `country` in your `malt` model can be null(it depends on application business logic). In case of nullable relations, accessing the model relation fields in `${model.relation.field}` pattern may produce above error. So you should use **null checking** inside your thymeleaf template in those cases.

Comment: Thanks, I've change what you suggested + I've deleted cascade options for Country in Malt model - it is working right now. I need to think about some validation, as you mentioned befor.